# Button not rendering the same in all broswers

Tags: html, css

Below is the CSS code which I have created to draw a button. When I view this in Chrome, the button looks circular as it should, but on Firefox and IE, it’s square. Why this would be the case?

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .button {
        width:90px;
        float:right;
        background:#FEDA71;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#FEDA71),color-stop(100%,#FEBB49));
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
        background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
        background:linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
        padding:8px 18px;
        color:#623F1D;
        font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
        font-size:16px;
        -moz-border-radius:48px;
        -webkit-border-radius:48px;
        border:1px solid #623F1D
    }
```

The code below has made Firefox start working but IE Still Doesnt Work

```
Code after change and still doensnt work

background:#FEDA71;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#FEDA71),color-stop(100%,#FEBB49));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,#FEDA71 0%,#FEBB49 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FEDA71',endColorstr='#FEBB49',GradientType=0);
    padding:8px 18px;
    color:#623F1D;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    border-radius:48px;
    -moz-border-radius:48px;
    -webkit-border-radius:48px;
    border:1px solid #623F1D
```

Comment: Add this: border-radius: 48px; Read more about CSS3 `border-radius` [here.](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren’t using the unprefixed version of the `border-radius` property, just `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius`. (Both engines have long supported the `border-radius` property without a vendor prefix, by the way — [Chrome since 5.0 and Firefox since 4.0](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) — so unless this is for a reason, don’t bother using those.)

Comment: @user2108195: In both Firefox and IE? Which versions of each? Is IE in Compatibility Mode?

Comment: it work fine on firefox but still not on IE and the version is 9

Comment: @user2108195: Press F12. Is IE in Compatibility Mode? (Top bar in the Developer Tools window.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
-moz-border-radius:48px;
-webkit-border-radius:48px;
border-radius:48px;
```

For older IE version you might want to give PIE a try http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 0):

[`-moz-border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/border-radius) was dropped from Gecko 13.0 as an alias for `border-radius` which was released as [Firefox 13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_13) on 2012-06-05, so any later version of Firefox does not support the `-moz` prefix for `border-radius` which is why Firefox isn't applying the style.

`-webkit-border-radius` is still supported as an alias, which is why the style is being applied in Chrome.

As others have pointed out, adding the unprefixed `border-radius` will correct the missing style for Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following code:

```
border-radius:48px;      //W3C
```

Comment: `-ms-border-radius` has never existed.

Comment: Hopefully, it will never exist.

Comment: `-o-border-radius` has also never existed.